# Creating a grow-on-demand loop filesystem without sparse files

Tags: filesystems, mount, root-filesystem, loop-device

I wish to create a file to loop mount as a root filesystem that grows dynamically as required (up to a limit).

The commonly quoted solution to this is to use a sparse file, which would do exactly what I want, however I wish to do this with fat32 / exfat (for compatibility across operating systems) as the host filesystem, neither of which support sparse files.

Is there an automated / semi-automated way to do this without rolling my own filesystem / loop driver?

Comment: How about a qcow2 file accessed via `qemu-nbd`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That does what I want, thankyou. I'll write it up as an answer unless you'd like to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[qemu-nbd](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/qemu-utils/qemu-nbd.8.en.html) can be used to bind a qemu image (a grow-on-demand qcow2 image) to a block device, which can then be mounted as a filesystem of choice.

With this method however, performance as a root filesystem is very poor, and the image size grows very quickly with the resulting image being 6~7 times larger than an equivalent squashfs after short use.

A qcow2 image (unpartitioned, ext4) can be mounted with:

```
# qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 --persistent /path/to/image.qcow2
# mount -t ext4 /dev/nbd0 /path/to/mountpoint/
```